# Adding multiple Web.config files in separate directories to WIX installer

Tags: asp.net, wix, installation

I am creating a Wix installer package for my ASP.net application, but am getting an error when trying to add multiple Web.config files even though they are located in different directories.

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Site" >
  <Component Id="Web.Config" Guid="F9D6C6E5-887E-4D90-BDEB-5D16AAA8F194">
    <File DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)\publish\Web.config" />
  </Component>
  <Directory Id="Account.Dir" Name="Account">
    <Component Id="Account.Web.Config" Guid="53FC1820-3ADD-41C0-92D6-9A66348C33A4">
      <File DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)\publish\Account\Web.config" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<Feature Id="DefaultFeature" ConfigurableDirectory="TARGETDIR" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="Web.Config"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="Account.Web.Config"/>
<Feature>
```

The error message I'm getting is: `"Duplicate symbol 'File:Web.config' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique."`

As far as I know you can't install the same file twice using WIX, but these are different files in different locations that only have the same name. When I rename one of the files the installer works as expected but this doesn't help since both files need to be named Web.config. I don't think that the IDs or GUIDs are a problem since they are unique and changing the file name works.

Does anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message correct but doesn't acknowledge that Id is being generated by WiX. To reduce clutter, successive versions of WiX have increasingly allowing certain attributes to be omitted since they generally don't need to be referenced in other parts of the authoring.

Per the [schema documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_file.htm) File/@Id must be unique.

> The unique identifier for this File element. If you omit Id, it
>   defaults to the file name portion of the Source attribute, if
>   specified. May be referenced as a Property by specifying [#value].

You just need to an Id attribute to one or both of the File elements so that assigned and generated File/@Id elements are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Give each file element a unique ID attribute:

```
<File Id="Web" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)\publish\Web.config" />

   <File Id="Account" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)\publish\Account\Web.config" />
```